# $R$ is a relation, let $a R^* b$ if and only if $a R b$ is true and $b R a$ is false. $R$ is transitive. Is $R^*$ also transitive? antisymmetric?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $R$ is a relation in a set $S$, define a new relation $R^*$ as follows: for each $a$ and $b$ in $S$, let $a R^* b$ if and only if $a R b$ is true and $b R a$ is false. Suppose that $R$ is transitive. Is $R^*$ also transitive? Is $R^*$ necessarily antisymmetric?

I think $R^*$ is not necessary transitive. Assume $aR^*b$ and $bR^*c$, then $aRb$ and $bRc$, then $aRc$ is true; and although $aRb$ and $bRc$ are false, $aRc$ seems not necessary to be false. But I can't find a concrete counterexample for this.

And I think $R^*$ should be antisymmetric. Since if $aR^*b$, then $aRb$ is true and $bRa$ is false, and $bR^*a$ means $bRa$ is true and $aRb$ is false, so $aR^*b$ and $bR^*a$ can not both be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if $R^*$ is transitive, suppose you have $aR^*b, bR^*c$.

By definition of $R^*$, this implies $aRb, bRc$. Since $R$ is transitive, this implies $aRc$.

So, $aR^*c$ if and only if $cRa$ is false.

Suppose $cRa$ is true. Then you have $bRc$ and $cRa$, so since $R$ is transitive, you must also have $bRa$. However, we started with the assumption that $aR^*b$ is true, which implies $bRa$ is false. This is a contradiction, so our supposition that $cRa$ is true must be false.

Thus, $aR^*c$ must be true, which implies $R^*$ is, indeed, transitive.

Your argument for why $R^*$ is antisymmetric is correct.